# Slim framework v3 route conditions

Tags: php, routes, slim

in Slim v2 we had these conditionals to define routes

```
$app->get('/:route', function($route) use($app) {
    //Code goes here
})->conditions(array('route' => 'route1|route2|route3'));
```

My question is, how can I replicate this in Slim v3?
Thank you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Slim 3 uses [FastRoute](https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute), so the format is: `{name:regular expression conditional}`.

In your case, you need:

```
$app->get('/{route:route1|route2|route3}', function($request, $response, $args) {
    $route = $args['route'];
    // code here
});
```